# Analysing English Text Sentences To Detect Rhymes in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, text, lexical-analysis

I'm not sure if this is possible, but is there a way (pre-written library or known scientific detection scheme) to analyse a few sentences of text and determine if the sentences rhyme? A colleague suggested comparing the first and last word and using a thesaurus, but I don't quite understand how that would work.

High accuracy is not what I am aiming for, an accuracy of even 20% would be awesome, it's for a gimmicky little web application idea I have nothing important just thought it would be cool.

I am open to trying other languages, perhaps even Python which I've heard is great for analysing text but PHP would be preferable.

Comment: Sorry Hakre, yes for English text only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Metaphone http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php

You could classify an input into phonetics (sounds) and then check if the same sound appears frequently. Since each one should match up with syllables, you could calculate the Levenshtein distance (count the syllables between the matches) to see if they fit into some known pattern, I.e. haiku.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php

Comment: Wow, just wow. I didn't even know those functions existed within PHP. I think you're onto something here. Considering the basis of a rhyme is similar sounding words, a combination of those 3 functions would indeed yield a very high accuracy rate for detecting rhymes.

Comment: @Dwayne: Leave a link here if you get something up running, even if it's something sandboxed only.

Comment: No worries Hakre, I was planning on it. Already got a domain name purchased for it as well. I'm trying to create a 1 hour app once a week as a development exercise to help break out of the daily work grind. Hopefully it works out, might be fun. The idea is to generate rhymes based on Twitter tweets.

Comment: @Dwayne I would be very interested to see what you come up with, good luck!

Comment: @DwayneCharrington Any chances your project is still alive ?